# Issue with specifying size of a vector

Tags: string

I want to create a vector that will hold strings but the size of the vector will be determined by the number of strings input by the user until they enter quit. How can I make a vector without knowing the size of it. If anyone can point me in the right direction i would really appreciate it.

My code is as follows:

```
1#include<iostream>
2 #include<string>
3 #include<cctype>
4 #include<vector>
5 using namespace std;
6 
7 void str_to_upper(string &s);
8 void reverse(string &s);
9 bool is_palindrome(string s);
10 void fill_vector( vector<string> &v);
11 void print_vector( vector<string> v );
12 void print_palindromes( vector<string> v);
13 void change_to_upper(vector<string> &v);
14 
15 int main()
16 {
17  int size;
18  vector<string> v();
19  for(int i = 0; v[i] != "quit"; i++) 
20  {
21   getline(cin, v[i];
22  }
```

Answer (score 1):

A C++ vector grows and shrinks dynamically. Unlike an array, you don't need to specify an explicit size. The constructor handles it.

If you add more than it can currently hold, it will resize itself. Same goes for removing. Have a look:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector